# Invalid data updating form error when updating textvalidation of item

Tags: google-apps-script

I use the following code to update textvalidation with a string:

```
function updateform(strtokens) {

  var form = FormApp.openById(#formid#);
  var textItem = form.getItemById(#formid#);
  var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
 .requireTextMatchesPattern(strtokens)
 .build();

textItem.asTextItem().setValidation(textValidation);

return form.getPublishedUrl();

}
```

I get error saying `invalid data updating form` at line `textItem.asTextItem().setValidation(textValidation)`

I get this issue on occasion but not all the time and i can't figure out why.

Are any of the following issues possible explanation?

- strtokens is of the format: `text1|text2|text3|..` etc, it can be very long. `text1`, etc also include special characters. note strtokens is concatenates randomly generated text of length 10 and the # of text is currently set to 10.
  The text is generated by randomly sampling 10 characters from `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` & special characters. please see examples below where they cause and do not cause error.
- Does the form id/item id change so that it doesn't identify accurately? I got form id from the url and I got item id from inspecting the id in the html of the form.

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of `strtokens` when the error occurs? Or can I ask you about the difference the values with and without the error?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for response. the text that make up strtokens are generated every time script runs by randomly sampling 10 characters from A-Z, a-z, 0-9 & special characters. strtokens is produced by concatenating generated text in this way: text1|text2|text3|...etc so that validation is either/or text. the # of text can be large, but i have seen error with sample numbers also pop up on occasion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that when the value of `strtokens` for replicating the error can be obtained, it might lead to the reason of the issue.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks here is the strtokens that reproduced the error: WvGMkRIQf>|X2ANqg<SGu|j$aN6on**L|v5$N#z7dW!|XU5#5Ml&8Q|Bz%EzuWLiE|a&Cv!IE3E4|-IK4>#ljA8|5ytvZeRJLd|dAOe2L6-g7|P>1UQ<iMYO|yoCZrb7Tom|cuIfBUN%js|FfIq2ASpF0|gZDf8abN1p|mHV>swDHwR|rDgknKK3CS|<$dbw0TfvO|K6xCL&zqk5

Comment: @Tanaike this one doesn't produce an error: hFI*ek0Ypa|>O3eLWaNyI|34UGs*BGWG|4xTlqI5$1v|6J5b4hxhQB|e!UGlGUe!d|RuQgm!07UR|JSe%zMrw84|kEffwcplYp|V#EOUi9xrK|mxxLLZ9rcJ|Z8-PgwizSH|j#lPl3nt3l|q$qzansAMi|<>FOR&yGl2|O0@hIat24N|7DVrI>Oz!5|BgmHjZpoC<|Q53a0cwxw<

Comment: @Tanaike i noticed 1st text hFIek0Ypa above has a * missing after the l when i paste it here

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, how about recreating `strtokens` using `try...catch` when the error occurs? By this, the value without the error can be used. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for response. the strtokens are generated in another function. any ideas? note i'm kinda new to this. thanks again.

Comment: @Tanaike i limited it to 2 text only to help find the issue. strtoken with error: *<R2&$fKfz|x&c&mmNdgT & strtoken without error: mOU-4p%ArY|o>&cL!JMeN

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation because I cannot understand about your whole script, when you use the random values as `strtokens`, I thought that in your case, the value without the error might be able to be used by recreating `strtokens` using `try...catch`. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `pattern` parameter you pass into `.requireTextMatchesPattern(pattern)` is a Regular Expression and the `*` character is a RegEx quantifier. If incorrectly used the pattern will be invalid and throws an error.*

#### More Information:

For Regular Expressions, the `*` character indicates:

> Zero or more occurances of the previous element.

**For example:**

- For the expression `stacko*verflow` the following strings will match:
- `stackverflow`
- `stackoverflow`
- `stackooverflow`
- `stackoooverflow`
- `stackoooverflow`

And so on, provided the string starts with `stack` and ends with `verflow`.

In the examples you provided in the above comments, you have the following Regular Expressions:

1:

```regex
WvGMkRIQf>|X2ANqg<SGu|j$aN6on**L|v5$N#z7dW!|XU5#5Ml&8Q|Bz%EzuWLiE|a&Cv!IE3E4|-IK4>#ljA8|5ytvZeRJLd|dAOe2L6-g7|P>1UQ<iMYO|yoCZrb7Tom|cuIfBUN%js|FfIq2ASpF0|gZDf8abN1p|mHV>swDHwR|rDgknKK3CS|<$dbw0TfvO|K6xCL&zqk5
```

2:

```regex
hFI*ek0Ypa|>O3eLWaNyI|34UGs*BGWG|4xTlqI5$1v|6J5b4hxhQB|e!UGlGUe!d|RuQgm!07UR|JSe%zMrw84|kEffwcplYp|V#EOUi9xrK|mxxLLZ9rcJ|Z8-PgwizSH|j#lPl3nt3l|q$qzansAMi|<>FOR&yGl2|O0@hIat24N|7DVrI>Oz!5|BgmHjZpoC<|Q53a0cwxw<
```

3:

```regex
mOU-4p%ArY|o>&cL!JMeN
```

4:

```regex
*<R2&$fKfz|x&c&mmNdgT
```

You can test these for yourself using an online [Regular Expression validator](https://regex101.com/) but I will explain this here.

In the first example, the culprit is the third string: `j$aN6on**L`. A double asterisk (`**`) is not a valid expression as the first asterisk would need to be escaped with a `\` (`j$aN6on\**L`).

The second example does not throw an error as it validates correctly. The same can be said about the third example.

The fourth example also throws an error - this time however it is due to the string starting with the `*` character. As the `*` character indicates zero or more occurances of the ***previous*** element, but there is no character before the `*`.

You can check out the [basic concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) of Regular Expressions to get a more detailed understanding.

#### References:

- [Wikipedia - Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

  - [Regular Expression - Basic concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts)

Comment: thanks for your detailed response. am i right to presume that it's primarily the use of '*' that is causing the issue? or are there other combinations with special characters that might throw an error? i am trying to ultimately figure out what special characters i should ignore in the generation of the tokens such that there is no such error again. thanks.

Comment: There are quite a few different characters that are used - `[\^$.|?*+()`but also there are some which while won't cause problems on their own, in very specific combinations will (for example `{` isn't a problem but `{n}` would be. You can have a look at a special characters list [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html).